# How do I create a map that is not to scale in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, scale

I want to make a map that isn't to scale and I'm so used to being pedantic about CRS and scale that I don't know where to start.

The map that I need to make is a simple guide for people to get to a site that is out of town.

I'm addicted to QGIS, of course.

Comment: Trying not to be rude, stop being pedantic about CRS. CRS are your friend you know? :-P

Comment: Take a look at the answer to this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/184404/given-wgs84-bounding-box-is-there-service-that-returns-most-accurate-projection/184442 the answer to your problem may be that you just need to define the right projection for your map

Answer (score 4):

Just use a generic coordinate reference system (CRS), like WGS84.

WGS84 is a global CRS, and will suffice. If you want, use an OpenLayers layer as a base map and digitise on top of that. Here's how to create a layer with a CRS: [choose WGS 84](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjE06.png)

Finally, if you just want a mud-map, why not use a drawing program? You'll be faster, probably. Also, you can use Google Directions to set up a nice simple URL for directions from anyone's current position, for example: https://www.google.com/maps/preview/dir//Louvre+Museum,+75001+Paris,+France/@48.8609709,2.3361075,19z

Comment: Thanks for responding. I was hoping that there may have been another way.  I realise I could have used a drawing program, but my drawing skills are limited. I wanted to retain the 'shape' of the route without dealing with the 'space' needed. Using a CRS to underpin the map still adds the 'space' - if you know what I mean.

Comment: Doesn't make much sense, @Johanna, you can still draw arbitrarily with a coordinate system...

Comment: Perhaps I am confused.  Can you explain what you mean by 'drawing with a coordinate system'?

Comment: In a drawing program, like GIMP, or Inkscape (or photoshop, whatever), when y ou draw something, it still uses a coordinate system, but it uses pixels or some other arbitrary grid to know where things are.

In GIS, you use a defined coordinate reference system to know where things are in relation to the world. For what you want to do, you don't care where you are in the world, so just use the default CRS and stick with it. Just start drawing!

Answer (score 3):

If you don't care about the scale and position on your map features, and since **QGIS needs to work with one CRS anyway**, just choose any CRS of your choice, and keep that choice for the entire  project.

By default, QGIS will open a new projects with EPGS 4326 (you can check that in the lower right corner of QGIS), so whenever QGIS asks what CRS to use (for example when you create a new layer) just use the same. And that's it, you can simply draw freely without worry about CRS anymore.

Obviously, keep in mind that doing it this way, the scale, coordinates, metric and angular measurements will mean absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, you want to create a sketch/tourist-style map, have data, a GIS but limited drawing skills (rather like myself!). QGIS is not really setup for this but what I would try in your situation would be to:

1. Create my map as usual in QGIS but with no labels and no point symbols (actually see point 4 below).  Save the map out of composer as an image.
2. Now switch to your image editor.  Cut the legend off and save that portion for future use.
3. Now scale the remainder of the map to fit the space available (making sure there is no scale bar etc!).
4. Next add your labels and point symbols (it's not to scale so being approximate is OK (you could even have little point symbols in QGIS and use them as a guide for this stage and place your new symbols on top).
5. Save your map

Now you have a choice, if the map is going into a brochure or gate-fold leaflet with other text, I would switch to my word processing package and pull in the map and the legend separately and arrange them in the document that way.  If it is just a single sheet with no other text etc, then I would reattach the undistorted legend in the image editor before saving then final version.

Comment: thank you @mappagnosis, your description of the workflow is clear and concise. I can follow that.

Answer (score 0):

Basically a GIS is not designed to print static images like the map you want to create but to *display data* which may vary in time and space. However every static map (for example a paper-map) can be produced using a GIS. This can be achieved by a two-step-process where the first (the data-)-part is handled within the GIS, and the second one (the actual design) by any graphics-program like **PhotoShop**.

Of course you can also produce a fine and static map by QGIS when you simply delete all the "space"-relevant information such as a scale, the north-arrow and any grid away.

This however should not affect the way you´re working with the *data* itself in the GIS. Thus defining any arbitrary CRS as supposed in the previous answers should work absoluetely fine for you. Simply draw every feature within that CRS and live with it - it won´t neccessarily appear on your printed product (be it on paper or on PDF or whateever you determine by "static") if you don´t want it to.

This also gives you the ability to update the map when your data changes as the actual space-context is still active within the data.

Another appraoch without even using a GIS would be by using a vector-based graphic-program such as **Adobe Illustrator** where you can *layout* any map. The approach is comparable in some aspects (e.g. layer-based processing) to your work in a GIS, also you have to digituze your shapes. However you have much more opportunities on actual *designing and layouting* your map.